# send error string from python script to jenkins job on failure

Tags: python, jenkins, post-build

i have a python script which is called from `jenkins` job shell script. This python script could fail for multiple reasons. Based on the failure i need to catch the correct failure reason. I want this reason to be sent back to `jenkins` shell some how and i will post this error message through an email or some other means of notification. I tried setting a environment variable and access it in post build. But that doesn't seem to work. Any help appreciated. Below is the sample text code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a=False
b=True
if(a):
    raise exception("a is true")
if(b):
    raise exception("b is true")
```

I need this `"a is true"` or `"b is true"` response sent back to `jenkins` shell and to fail the job.

Comment: what have you tried so far? Because if your script throws an exception, it should result in failure on jenkins end

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to exit with exception? it will mark Jenkins job failed.

Better to exit python script with some message or code except `1` and the handle the message or code at Jenkins side.

Now you modify the python script

```
#!/usr/bin/python
a=False
b=True
if(a):
    print ("a is true")
    exit(0)
if(b):
    print ("b is true")
    exit(0)
```

In the above, your job will not be marked failed and you will able to handle the job status on Jenkins instead from the python script.

In Jenkins bash script

```
script_response=$(python ab.py)

if [ "${script_response}" == "b is true" ]; then
   echo "B is true"
   exit 0
 else
   echo "B is flase"
   exit 1
fi
```